# Xcode xcframework errors, like Unknown attribute 'Combine.Published'

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, swiftui, xcframework

I'm trying to compile my framework into an xcframework, which I do with the following script:

```
xcodebuild archive \
  -scheme CleanUI \
  -configuration Release \
  -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' \
  -archivePath './build/CleanUI.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive' \
  SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
  BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild archive \
  -scheme CleanUI \
  -configuration Release \
  -destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator' \
  -archivePath './build/CleanUI.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive' \
  SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
  BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
  -framework './build/CleanUI.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/CleanUI.framework' \
  -framework './build/CleanUI.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/CleanUI.framework' \
  -output './build/CleanUI.xcframework'
```

This works completely fine until I import the CleanUI.xcframework into a test project. I get the following errors:

[image]

[image]

All those errors make no sense, at all. When I build the framework as a normal framework, with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, everything works fine.

I deleted the derived data folder, cleaned every build folder and restarted my Mac like a thousand times. I have been working on this for the past 10 hours, I feel like I searched the entire web and tried every single possible solution.

Comment: What's the deployment target of your test project, the fact that it says it can't find Combine, gives us the possibility that it might be set lower than 13, although if you created a new project it's unlikely, but worth asking.

Comment: All of the test projects have a minimum deployment target of iOS 15.

Comment: @Pitchbloas are you able to fix it? I am also facing same issue. Building framework is working fine, but when i import it into other project, I am also seeing same error..

Comment: Yes i was! You just need to specifically ``import Combine`` everywhere you use it. Seems dumb, but that was the issue.